# Update Statement with Case in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I have this issue and I have investigated more than five house but find nothing :( . I have table called support.

```
UPDATE support s SET    s.Survey_Status = 0
CASE 
WHEN s.Survey_Status = 0 Then 1
WHEN s.Survey_Status = 1 Then 2 
End 
Where last_response < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
and support_waiting ="n" ;
```

I need to update the support table and set the survey_status =1 except the fifth row in the table will be =2 . For example, if I have survey_ status from 1 to 10 = 1 then the fifth will =2 . any idea please  ??
By the way, I am working with mysql Heidi .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Meaningless without an ordering.

Comment: Ismail, could you add sample data and expected results? Also describe what you mean by "fifth row" - is it defined by a column (easy) or by its "natural order" within the table (difficult).

Comment: @EdGibbs: What's a "natural order" within a table?

Comment: @eggyal - I meant the order in which the row shows up when you do `SELECT * FROM myTable` without an `ORDER BY`. I picked that term up from a comment on an SO posting a while back; hardly an authoritative source now that I think about it :)

Comment: @EdGibbs: Ah, okay. There's nothing to guarantee that order will be consistent from one query to the next.

Comment: Exactly. Unfortunately a lot of questions here presuppose the order *will* be consistent so I wanted to see if the OP was counting on that. If so I was planning to warn them the answer could be difficult (because they'd need a counter, as your answer uses) or unreliable (unless they `ORDER BY` something, as your answer does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html) and [`MOD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod):

```
UPDATE   support, (SELECT @r:=0) init
SET      Survey_Status = IF(MOD(@r:=@r+1,5), 1, 2)
WHERE    last_response < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
     AND support_waiting = 'n'
ORDER BY ...
```